# Selenium+Firefox Webdriver - ошибка sendkeys для элемента input

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Элемент на странице, к которому обращаюсь

```
<input type="file" class="hidden-file-input-with-label" id="upload_photo_input_a2e00ec0-a651-4368-94a3-b5a8c714882f" accept="image/*" capture="" name="image">
```

Пытаюсь передать ему путь к изображению и выполнить действие(Условный код):

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(link)
upload_photo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
upload_photo.send_keys("path to file on disk")
upload_photo.submit()
```

Элемент находит элемент, на следующей строке upload_photo.send_keys("path to file on disk"), получаю ошибку:

```
Error Message: POST /session/c3607bab-8b72-4316-9319-2054332c3830/file did not match a known command
```

Использование upload_photo.clear() до send_keys не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, это проблема с webdriver.Firefox(), на связке selenium+PhantomJS - данный код работает без ошибок

Answer (score 1):

Если SendKeys() отказывается передавать введенную информацию, рекомендую пробовать обновлять драйвер для того или иного браузера. Сам сталкивался с подобными проблемами, но после загрузки последней версии они исчезали.